# Multiple arrays with same indexs in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I want to save records from array in php.I get arrays like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Make
    [1] => Model
    [2] => Year
    [3] => SKU
)

Array
(
    [0] => HTC
    [1] => Diamond
    [2] => 2008
    [3] => HTC Touch Diamond
)

Array
(
    [0] => Samsung
    [1] => M-900
    [2] => 2007
    [3] => MM-A900M
)

Array
(
    [0] => AT&T
    [1] => PDA
    [2] => 2002
    [3] => 8525PDA
)

Array
(
    [0] => AT&T
    [1] => PDA
    [2] => 2003
    [3] => 8525PDA
).
```

The above data coming from foreach loop like `foreach($data as $row){ print_r($row);}`.Now i want to save lower records against first array indexs like make,model,year and sku.The array index( make,model,year,sku) can be less or more means dynamic.How can i do that ? Thnaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$cnt = 0;
$res = array();
foreach($data as $row){
   if($cnt ==0){
      $key   = array();
      $key   = $row;
      $cnt++;
   }
   else{
     $res[]  = array_combine($key,$row);
   }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use build-in function [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine)

Comment: Thanks for your response.How can i combine them in loop ?

Comment: Sure `foreach ($arrays_values as $array_values) $model_values[] = array_combine($array_keys, $array_values);`